# Yammer Expected redirect

Tags: c#, yammer

I need to write a custom integration with **Yammer**

I'm using my `localhost:12343` in Visual Studio and after logging onto yammer, the redirect does not work because, of course, it is pointing to localhost.

Is there a work around? does one need an internet facing URL for the redirect to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Yammer URL to trusted sites. That solved the redirect blank page.